# getting error while accessing vimeo advanced api

Tags: iphone, objective-c, vimeo

i am getting this error in json format while fetching vimeo advanced search api this is the error

```
{"code":"401","expl":"The oauth_token passed has not been authorized by the user.","msg":"Invalid token"}}
```

this is my code for authentication on vimeo .

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:@"xxxxxxxxxxxx"
                                                    secret:@"xxxxxxxxxxxx"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://vimeo.com/oauth/request_token"];

    OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                                                   consumer:consumer
                                                                      token:nil   // we don't have a Token yet
                                                                      realm:nil   // our service provider doesn't specify a realm
                                                          signatureProvider:nil]; // use the default method, HMAC-SHA1

    [request setParameters: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName: @"oauth_callback" value: @"http://iosdevelopertips.com/networking/iphone-json-flickr-tutorial-part-1.html"] ,nil]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];

    [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                         delegate:self
                didFinishSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket:didFinishWithData:)
                  didFailSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket:didFailWithError:)];

}

- (void)requestTokenTicket:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinishWithData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"ticket value %@",ticket);
    if (ticket.didSucceed) {
        NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        requestToken = [[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:responseBody];
    }
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://vimeo.com/oauth/authorize?auth_token=%@", requestToken.key];
    NSURL *urlAuth = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlAuth];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?method=vimeo.videos.search"];
    OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                                                   consumer:consumer
                                                                      token:requestToken
                                                                      realm:nil
                                                          signatureProvider:[[OAHMAC_SHA1SignatureProvider alloc] init]];

    OARequestParameter *nameParam = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"format"
                                                                       value:@"json"];
    OARequestParameter *descParam = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"query"
                                                                       value:@"amir khan"];
    NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nameParam, descParam, nil];
    [request setParameters:params];

    OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
    [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                         delegate:self
                didFinishSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket2:didFinishWithData:)
                  didFailSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket2:didFinishWithData:)];
}

- (void)requestTokenTicket2:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinishWithData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"data string %@",dataString);
}
```

Comment: *sidenote:* never show your credentials to public

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue was?

Comment: Hi, Did you got the answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

The error message "The oauth_token passed has not been authorized by the user" means that you are using the request token, and not the access token.

The request token is the token you get before the user has authenticated with your app.
This token is used in building the url that you send your users to.

Once the user has approved your app on vimeo.com, they will be redirected to your app. At this time you should exchange your request token for an access token.